# How to connect 2 docker containers via host one?

Tags: docker-compose

I'm having a nginx proxy container as a host and would like to communicate between cms and mongo containers via localhost. Unfortunately localhost:27017 in not available from cms container.

How should I connect them to work as I need?

docker-compose configuration is the next:

```
version: '3'
services:
  proxy:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    privileged: true
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    network_mode: host
    depends_on:
      - cms
      - mongo
  cms:
    container_name: cms
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: cms
    env_file:
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
```

BTW: mongo-express has access to mongo container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Try to connect to `mongo` in `cms` using its service name: `mongo:27017`

or add `network_mode: host` to mongo service spec:

```
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    network_mode: host
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

and cms:

```
  cms:
    container_name: cms
    restart: unless-stopped
    build: cms
    network_mode: host
    env_file:
    links:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - '1337:1337'
```

if you want to connect to mongo using `localhost:27017` in `cms`